# VMFS recovery - how do you proceed?

Tags: vmware-esx, corruption, vmfs

The more I look into ESX the more often i have to handle cases where the partition table of a disk with a VMFS volume gets corrupted.
The reasons for this can be

```
* idiot user
* failed update
* power failure
* ....
```

I guess you guys must already have something like a usual procedure on how to work through this cases.

I am especially interested in a straight fast way to find out if the VMFS volume itself is corrupted beyond repair.

So far I use very time consuming attempts with scans with Testdisk and similar tools.
Do you have better / faster ways ?

Comment: this question may be migrated to ServerFault.com, our sister site that deals with server and enterprise technologies.  if that happens, you can register at ServerFault, and then associate your accounts on your user profile page.  then your SF account will regain control of this question (to edit, or accept an answer, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Well, first I would say that since TestDisk doesn't claim compatibility with VMFS, you are probably doing more harm than good using that tool against it.

A corrupt partition table is probably one of the last things I would think of ...  I just don't see that type of thing happening all that much.

What kind of symptoms are you seeing that makes you think that the VMFS partition table is corrupted? Honestly with the hundreds of ESX servers I've been working with over the past 3 years ... I've never seen a corrupted partition table (granted that doesn't mean much ... )

Comment: I'm with Zypher - I've *never* seen an ESX server suffer a corrupted partition table.